# Choosing method for multiple linear regression for 1 to 10 ratings

Tags: regression, rating

I'm performing a survey where people will rate some things from 1 to 10 based on their characteristics and I'm having trouble understanding which model to use and how to compile the data.

For example lets say that you ask women to rate men based on some data like length, weight, income, children (some of the variables like length and weight will correlate). You ask every woman to rate the same 10 men from 1 to 10 depending on how suitable they think they are as a partner (based only on the characteristics) and the goal is to find out if any of the variables can be ignored and then try to decide the weight of the remaining variables.

I'm trying to do this in R and from what I gather I should use a ordered logit model where the rating is my dependent variable, is that correct? But in what way should I compile my data, do I simply put all the responses after each other in one big file, even though they are rating the same 10 men? For example:
length, weight, income, children, rating
150, 50, 100000, 0, 1
160, 90, 200000, 0, 4
180, 90, 150000, 2, 6
...
170, 85, 300000, 0, 8
and then repeating with different ratings:
150, 50, 100000, 0, 2
160, 90, 200000, 0, 6
180, 90, 150000, 2, 3
...
170, 85, 300000, 0, 4

If there is any guide online with a similar problem I would love to see it!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry I am not clear as o what you are asking.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to input the data from the responses I get and what model to use. I've added an example of how I think the data should look in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't help you with how to input the data because it's off-topic. You haven't specified exactly what you want to do. This is my best guess:

> I have an ordinal response variable from 1-10 for women rating on men. 10 is better than 9, 9 is better than 8 and so on. I want to build a regression model on the rating. I have some predictors.

There is nothing stopping you from ordinal logit. If you want to use it, you will need to make the proportional odds assumption.

The regression predicts the log-odds of two cumulative probabilities, one less-than and the other greater-than type. This is the simplest and most common ordinal regression model.

The most common alternative is ordered probit. There'e others but I would just stick on these two until you are confident.